# Keep Generics in tact when line length is exceeded (ESLint)

Tags: typescript, eslint

Is there an ESLint property that will prevent breakage of generic chevron tags over several lines if the line length is exceeded? It just looks so messy the way it splits the generic.

**current behavior**

```
return this.http.post(url, verifyContactRequest, httpOptions) as Observable<
  ContactVerificationResponse
>
```

**desired behavior**

```
return this.http.post(url, verifyContactRequest, httpOptions) as 
    Observable<ContactVerificationResponse>
```

Comment: I think the problem is rather in Prettier (or other formatter) than in ESlint

Comment: yep I believe you're right. Just came across some github issues on something similar. Although, can't find the configuration option for it.